# Javascript Bootstrap | Open bootstrap modal with javascript and not with button

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

How can we open bootstrap modal with javascript and not with button? I need to open without button, because another javascript program will decide when to open the modal.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```html
<script>
  //...
  document.getElementById("modalElement").style.visibility = ""; 
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modalElement" class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.modal('show')`.

With jQuery it will be: `$('#modalElement').modal('show')`

Extracted from [Bootstrap Modal API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalshow)

Comment: <script>
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
</script> This is enough? (I am using bootstrap). Thanks.

Comment: @julian Seems alright as long as you have jQuery + Bootstrap loaded on your html page

Comment: Button open the modal, but this code doesn´t open. Why?

Comment: Now ok: <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
});
</script>  Thanks Liad Yogev!!

Answer (score 3):

This is for Bootstrap 5 but should work in lower versions as well.

```
document.querySelector(".modal").classList.add("show");
document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: While this answer works, it breaks the normal transitions that happen in a Bootstrap theme and requires additional unnecessary coding.

Answer (score 3):

This one works for Bootstrap 5

```java
new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector("#exampleModalCenter")).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const modalElement = document.getElementById('yourmodalid');
if(modalElement){ 
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElement); modal.show(); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. And maybe highlight the relevant additional original insight when compared to existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

answer using purely javascript

```
    var modalElement = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modalElement'))
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

or if your calling it asynchronously

```
    const modalElement = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance('#modalElement');
    modalElement.show();
```

[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#getorcreateinstance](https://bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance)

btw. you have two id attributes there. you must have only one id attribute in your element